# Python code to find minimum distance between points and a curve

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, distance

I have some data and I have plotted magnitude against wavelength (the blue points). I then have some code that reads a model stellar population from a file, and plots this on the same graph (the pink line). In this code, there is a scale that can be adjusted that moves this line up or down on the graph. So far I have been changing the scale so that the line is as close as I can tell by eye to my points, but I would like to write some code that would calculate the value of the scale for which the total distance between my points and the line is a minimum. This is my code so far:

```
#Import modules

from math import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Specify data

wavelength = 
np.array([357.389,445.832,472.355,547.783,620.246,752.243,891.252,2164.089])
magnitude = 
np.array([24.0394,23.1925,23.1642,22.4794,21.7496,20.9047,20.4671,19.427])

# Create Graph

#plt.scatter(wavelength, magnitude)
#plt.ylim([25,18])
#plt.xlim([300,2200])
#plt.xlabel('wavelength (nm)')
#plt.ylabel('magnitude')
#plt.title('object 1')
#plt.show()
#plt.close()

#now - here is some code that reads a model stellar population model from a 
file

lines = open('fig7b.dat').readlines()

wavelengths, luminosities = [],[]

for l in lines:
    s = l.split()
    wl = s[0]
    old = s[-1]
    if '#' not in wl:
        wavelengths.append(float(wl)) #wavelength in angstroms 
        luminosities.append(float(old)) #luminosities are in log units!


scale = 3.5
c=3.e8 
wavelengths = np.array(wavelengths)
nus = c/(wavelengths*1.e-10) 
luminosities = np.array(luminosities) + scale 

luminosity_density = np.log10(((10**luminosities)*wavelengths)/nus)

#plt.plot(wavelengths,luminosity_density)
#z = 1.0
#plt.plot(wavelengths*(1+z),luminosity_density,color='r')

#plt.axis([900, 10000, 25,31])
#plt.savefig('sed.png')
#plt.show()
#plt.close()

Mpc_to_cm = 3.086e24 #convert Mpc to cm 
z  = 0.3448 #our chosen redshift
D_L = 1841.7 * Mpc_to_cm 

#remember luminosity_density is logged at the moment
flux_density = (10**luminosity_density) * (1+z) / (4*pi*D_L**2) #units will 
be erg/s/cm^2/Hz

#now turn that into an AB magnitude - goes back to log
AB_mag = -2.5*np.log10(flux_density) - 48.6

#try plotting your photometry on here and play with z and D_L 
plt.plot(wavelengths*(1+z),AB_mag,color='pink')
plt.scatter(wavelength*10., magnitude,color='cornflowerblue')
plt.axis([900, 25000, 30,18])
plt.xlabel('wavelength')
plt.ylabel('magnitude')
plt.title('object 1')
plt.savefig('sed_ab.png')
plt.show()
```

which gives a graph that looks like this:

[image]

Also it would be helpful to print the best scale value.
I'm very new to python and programming in general and the pink line isn't a simple equation (in the file I was given it is made up of a lot of data points) so I have been getting a bit stuck. Apologies if I am not using the correct language to describe my problem, and for the long code - a lot of the comments were previous plots my supervisor has kept from before when I had separate plots. (I am using python 2.7)

A link to fig7b.dat: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_tOncLLEAYsbG8wcHJMYVowOXc

Comment: You could compute the RMS of data points to the model curve and minimize this via [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). Also take a look at [Goodness of fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit).

Comment: Any chance of getting a copy of `fig7b.dat`?

Comment: @HughBothwell I have uploaded a link at the bottom!

Answer (score 1):

First, create a list of points from the curve data so that each point corresponds to the first list of points (each corresponding pair of points will have the same X coordinate, i.e. the same wavelength).

Then the minimum distance between these two sets of points will simply be: `(sum(points2)-sum(points1))/len(points1)`.

Look at the following example

```
points1 = [1.1, 1.4, 1.8, 1.9, 2.3, 1.7, 1.9, 2.7]
points2 = [8.4, 3.5, 2.9, 7.6, 0.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.8]

def min_distance(first,second):
  assert len(first) == len(second)  # must have same size
  result = (sum(second) - sum(first)) / len(first)
  return result

print("Adding this value to the first series of points")
print("will provice minimum distance between curves")
print(min_distance(points1,points2))
```

Running this wil print value `2.25`. If you add `2.25` to all values of `points1`, you will get the minimum possible distance between the two sets of points (which is `62.36` in this particular case).

In your problem, `points1` will be the `magnitude` array.  `points2` will be the points from `fig7b.dat` corresponding to the wavelengths.

This assumes you want to minimize the sum of sqaures between the points and the curve.  It also assumes distances are measured vertically (that is why you need to extract the points with the corresponding wavelengths).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write your own little code without using spicy.optimize I
would recommend:

use an interpolation of your theoretical spectrum to evaluate the theoretical value at each of your observed wavelength:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html

e.g.:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d    
f2 = interp1d(wavelengths, luminosities, kind='cubic')
```

Than you can calculate \chi^{2} for every scale value you want to try and afterwards find the minumum.